# Wrap a single field with single quotes using awk

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, sed

There are a number of examples using awk to wrap fields with double quotes.  I have unsuccessfully been trying to enclose a field with single quotes for data loading csv files in postgresql.

Below are a few of my attempts:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}

{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
    if($i == 9)
    {
        $i = "\'' $i \''"
    }

  print $0 >> "output.csv"
}
```

or

`awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { $9= ""'" $9 ""'"} 1' container.csv > output.csv`

also...

```
awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN { FS="," } { sub($9, ""\'"&"\'"" );print}' container.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: BTW, you can use an arbitrary delimiter between fields during a data load. Use a delimiter that can't ever appear in your data -- say, the ASCII field separator character, if you've validated that it can't be present -- and you don't need to worry about quoting.

Comment: Thanks - will give it a go for the next table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { $9= "'"'"'" $9 "'"'"'"; print }' \
>    <<<one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,'nine',ten
```

The tricky thing here is getting your quotes through bash into awk -- if you have a single quote in your single-quoted command-line argument, it's treating as ending the quoting context that started at `'BEGIN`, not as a literal thing to be sent to `awk`.

Thus, `"'"'"'"` does the necessary trickery:

- The first character, `"`, is literal, passed to awk
- The second character, `'`, is syntactic, used to tell the shell to end the quotes that began at the front of the command line
- The third character, `"`, is syntactic, used to begin a new (double-quoted) quoting context.
- The fourth character, `'`, is literal inside that context.
- The fifth character, `"`, ends the double-quoting context started at character three
- The sixth character, `'`, is syntactic, resuming the single-quoted context ended by character two
- The seventh character, `"`, is literal, passed to awk.

Thus, what's **actually passed to `awk` to be used as a script in the above** is:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { $9= "'" $9 "'"; print }
```

...which you could just put directly in a file, if you preferred; if that awk script had a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` shebang, it should work when directly executed as a command.

---

If your shell is bash, by the way, there's an alternate quoting context that will make this much less awful:

```
$ awk $'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } { $9= "\'" $9 "\'"; print }'
```

Inside of `$''`, backslash escapes are honored -- `\t` is a tab, `\f` is field separator, `\r` is a newline, and -- relevant to our point -- `\'` is a single quote.

Comment: Works fine.  Much appreciated.  Thanks !

Comment: Wow, that's even more awful than I thought!

Comment: I've clarified to show `$''` syntax, which is a much less ugly way to do this on the command line if you know your shell is bash. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for mentioning `$''`.  Impressive stuff :)

Comment: @EdMorton, ...argh, you're right; I had it in my head that `-F` set both.

Answer (score 1):

This is *much* easier within a script, since you don't need to worry about the enclosing quotes:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

{ 
    $9 = "'" $9 "'"
    print
}
```

I'm not sure what your loop was supposed to be doing!

Testing using the input kindly provided by Charles:

```
$ cat file
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten
$ awk -f script.awk file
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,'nine',ten
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but awk is not liking it:
`awk '{ $9 = '"'"'$9'"'"' }' container.csv > test.csv

awk: cmd. line:1: { $9 = '$9' }
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: { $9 = '$9' }
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error`

Comment: @Stelios, yeah I got it wrong, hence the edit. I'd recommend using a script, as you can see in the current version of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the octal escape sequence `\047` wherever you need a single quote:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { $9= "\047" $9 "\047"; print }'
```

That avoids any complexity in quoting and any surprises that result from other approachess.

Comment: Might want to be clear that this is an awk-ism -- inside single-quotes, the shell won't interpret that -- but it's definitely a great solution for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `sed`

```
$ s='one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten'

$ # s///n means nth matching occurrence
$ echo "$s" | sed "s/[^,]*/'&'/9"
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,'nine',ten
$ # * used as quantifier so that it will work on empty fields too
$ echo 'a,c,,d' | sed "s/[^,]*/'&'/3"
a,c,'',d  

$ # or if hex escape sequences are allowed
$ # this is preferred as it avoids shell interpretation within double quotes
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/[^,]*/\x27&\x27/9'
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,'nine',ten
```